# Map an array and return a new one based on the object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the original array:

```
let list = [
    {
        city: "new york", 
        current_time: "123", 
        time1: "456", 
        time2: "789",
    },
    {
        city: "london",
        current_time: "123",
        time1: "456",
        time2: "789",
    },
    {
        city: "tokyo",
        current_time: "123",
        time1: "456",
        time2: "789",
    }
]
```

I'm trying to create an array of arrays where each inner array containing the objects with the city and time. But organized by **current_time**, **time1** or **time2**.

The expected result:

```
result = [
    [{
        city: "new york",
        time: "123"
    }, {
        city: "london",
        time: "123"
    }, {
        city: "tokyo",
        time: "123"
    }],
    [{
        city: "new york",
        time: "456"
    }, {
        city: "london",
        time: "456"
    }, {
        city: "tokyo",
        time: "456"
    }], [{
        city: "new york",
        time: "789"
    }, {
        city: "london",
        time: "789"
    }, {
        city: "tokyo",
        time: "789"
    }]
]
```

I tried to use map function, but I'm able to create the array just with the current_time, I probably need to iterate the keys but I'm confused if I need to use an forEach or a better way to iterate.

```
result = list.map((element, index) => {
    if(element.current_time) {
        return { city: element.city, time: element.current_time };
});
```

Comment: you are returning an object in the map function not an array with the 3 objects for the different times and even that is not enough since the city is not shared. so use list[id].city

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array for the keys and map the the result of mapped values of the given array.

```js
var list = [{ city: "new york", current_time: "123", time1: "456", time2: "789" }, { city: "london", current_time: "123", time1: "456", time2: "789" }, { city: "tokyo", current_time: "123", time1: "456", time2: "789" }],
    keys = ["current_time", "time1", "time2"],
    result = keys.map(k => list.map(o => ({ city: o.city, time: o[k] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An other approach could be to iterate the data and reduce it by iterating the keys for the assingning of objects with an index of the keys.

```js
var list = [{ city: "new york", current_time: "123", time1: "456", time2: "789" }, { city: "london", current_time: "123", time1: "456", time2: "789" }, { city: "tokyo", current_time: "123", time1: "456", time2: "789" }],
    keys = ["current_time", "time1", "time2"],
    result = list.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.forEach((k, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || []).push({ city: o.city, time: o[k] }));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly changed version for data with some missing keys.

```js
var list = [{ city: "new york", current_time: "123", time1: "456", time2: "789" }, { city: "london", time1: "456", time2: "789" }, { city: "tokyo", current_time: "123", time1: "456" }],
    keys = ["current_time", "time1", "time2"],
    result = list.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.forEach((k, i) => k in o && (r[i] = r[i] || []).push({ city: o.city, time: o[k] }));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just forgot one detail. Sometimes in the the list I won't have all the keys. For example an object just with current_time and time1. Should get this dynamically in the map?

Comment: you could add a check and push if the key exists, as in the third part.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you

```js
let list = [{
  city: "new york",
  current_time: "123",
  time1: "456",
  time2: "789"
}, {
  city: "london",
  current_time: "123",
  time1: "456",
  time2: "789"
}, {
  city: "tokyo",
  current_time: "123",
  time1: "456",
  time2: "789"
}, {
  city: "tokyo",
  current_time: "1223",
  time1: "456",
  time2: "789"
}, {
  city: "tokyo",
  current_time: "1223",
  time1: "456",
  time2: "789"
}],
obj = {};

list.forEach(function(itm) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(itm.current_time)) {
    obj[itm.current_time] = [];
  }
  obj[itm.current_time].push(itm);
});

let result = [];
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result.push(obj[keys[i]]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `map` creates a new array with the same length as the original, so, what you need to do is looping that array and group those values.

An alternative is using the function `reduce`

```js
let list = [{ city: "new york",   current_time: "123",   time1: "456",   time2: "789"}, { city: "london",   current_time: "123",   time1: "456",   time2: "789"},{ city: "tokyo",  current_time: "123",  time1: "456",  time2: "789"}],
    keys = ['current_time', 'time1', 'time2'],
    result = Object.values(list.reduce((a, c) => {
      keys.forEach(k => (a[c[k]] || (a[c[k]] = [])).push({ city: c.city, time: c[k] }));
      return a;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = [{
        city: "new york",
        current_time: "123",
        time1: "456",
        time2: "789",
    },
    {
        city: "london",
        current_time: "123",
        time1: "456",
        time2: "789",
    },
    {
        city: "tokyo",
        current_time: "123",
        time1: "456",
        time2: "789",
    }
];
let timeKeys = Object.keys(list[0]);
timeKeys.shift();
let finalArray = timeKeys.map(val => list.map(nestedVal => ({
    city: nestedVal.city,
    time: nestedVal[val]
})));

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the approach to defined a new empty array and resetting to empty for each element. this array is been populated by running through the loop of each element property which is not the city and pushing a new object with property city and time.

Hope it would be helpful.

```js
var list = [
{ city: "new york", 
  current_time: "123", 
  time1: "456", 
  time2: "789",
},
 { city: "london",
   current_time: "123",
   time1: "456",
   time2: "789",
},
{ city: "tokyo",
  current_time: "123",
  time1: "456",
  time2: "789",
}];
var arr = []
var result = list.map((ele) => {
   arr = []
   for(var prop in ele){
      if(prop != 'city') arr.push({city: ele['city'], time: ele[prop]})
     }
    return arr
  })
  
console.log('result =', result)
```